# How to include Openframeworks header within opencv code?

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, openframeworks

This is a somewhat noob question.. I am trying display opencv images in OpenFrameworks. I am not using codeblocks or any specific IDE. I tried including the header file paths into the makefile, but was unable to run the code successfully.

For example, I have a test program such as

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>


#include "ofMain.h"
#include "testApp.h"
#include "ofAppGlutWindow.h"



using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{    
    ofAppGlutWindow window;
    ofSetupOpenGL(&amp;window, 300, 300, OF_WINDOW);        
    ofRunApp( new testApp());


}
```

The flags in the makefile look like this

```
OF_FLAGS =  -L../../../libs/openFrameworks/ -L../../../libs/openFrameworks/app

INCL     = -I/usr/local/include 

LIBS     = -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui
```

How do I exactly include the ofMain.h, testApp.h and ofAppGlutWindow.h paths into the makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to use OpenCV with openFrameworks and don't want to do some super fancy custom stuff, I would recommend just looking at the open cv examples, which are bundled with openFrameworks. Just look in the `<of folder>/examples/addons` folder and try to compile `opencvExample` or `opencvHaarFinderExample`. If there are no Makefiles in the folder, try to generate them with the ofProjectGenerator. If everything is setup right, there is no need for manually change config.make or the Makefile of an example.
If the examples are the right direction for you, copy them, rename them and start your own project out of this.

Comment: Hi, I did try using the opencv example from under addons, copied them, made some modifications and tried to use simple opencv functions from within them. But I'm still unable to run them properly. I did try modifying the makefile by adding in the opencv headers, etc. but when I tried to run the program it gave me a gstreamer error, even though i have configured opencv correctly with gstreamer.

Comment: do the opencv function work well in an example? did you copy yout app to the right location? be sure that OF_ROOT in your config.make points to the OF folder.

Comment: yes, I did make sure that OF_ROOT in config.make is the correct path. The opencv example works well within OF. However, if i try to use the actual OpenCV image formats, IplImage*, etc. I need to configure the makefile to add the opencv paths. This doesnt seem to work. My query is, whether OF is free enough to accept external OpenCV functions within its program? (without using ofxOpenCv.h)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the libs folder of ofxOpenCV is included in Build Settings > Search Paths > Header Search Paths.

[image]

In case it's not obvious, click on your XCode project in the upper left, then in the horizontal menu near the top, click on **Build Settings** and scroll down to **Search Paths**. Double click inside the value field for Header Search Paths and add `../../../addons/ofxOpenCV/libs`. Lastly, set the dropdown on the right to recursive.